# .NET Core Partial View Form doesn't register foreign key

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Okay, so in on of mine views i have a partial view which i call like this:

```
<partial name="_StoryFormPartial" model='new Story { BoardColumn = @boardColumn, StoryTitle = "test"}' >
```

As you can see i create a new model for the partial view, BoardColumn which is a model and StoryTitle. Both attributes if fully useable in the partial view. However, the partial view is a form and once i post this form i can no longer access BoardColumn in the contoller.

Here is my partial view:

```
        <form asp-controller="Story" asp-action="Create">
            <h1>@Model.BoardColumn.BoardColumnName</h1>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="BoardColumn" value="@Model.BoardColumn" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StoryTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StoryTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StoryTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a style="cursor:pointer;color:white;" id="close_form_@Model.BoardColumn.BoardColumnId" class="btn btn-danger">X</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

As i said once i post this i can no longer user Boardcolumn and i get the error message 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' I would appriciate any help i can get on this matter.

I solved this by sending the id instead and then find the right column in the controller, is their any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a complex object to an input - an input only posts back a single value.

If you want to post a Boardcolumn object to controller , you could change the following code :

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="BoardColumn" value="@Model.BoardColumn" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="BoardColumn.BoardColumnId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="BoardColumn.BoardColumnName" />
```

Result：
[image]

For the input tag helper with asp-for , you could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-input-tag-helper